# Calling Signed Java Applet from Java Script Security Issues

Tags: java, javascript, security, applet

I have a signed Java Applet that has the following method:

```
public Boolean SaveToFile(String text)
{
File file = new File("c:\\myFile.txt");

// if file doesnt exists, then create it 
if ( ! file.exists( ) )
{
    file.createNewFile( );
}

file.setReadable(true);
file.setWritable(true);
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter( file.getAbsoluteFile( ) );
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( fw );
bw.write( text );
bw.close( );
return true;
```

}

When i call this method from a button inside the applet, it creates the file without any problems.

The problem is when i call this method from java script, i have the following exception:

```
access denied (java.io.FilePermission c:\myFile.txt read)
```

How can i fix this exception?

Comment: try to wrap your code with AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>() { ... }); Check it out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html

Comment: i tried using AccessController but i have the same exception\

Comment: if you use maven to build this applet jar, do you have in build/plubins/plugin{maven-jar-plugin}/configuration/archive/manifestEntries : tag <Permissions>all-permissions</Permissions> ?

Comment: i am using NetBeans and i have the following line in my manifest file: permissions: all-permissions
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *

Comment: *"i tried using AccessController but i have the same exception"* It is the only solution for this.  Show the updated code.  Put something in the code to prove the JRE is ***using*** the new code rather than a cached copy of the Jar.

Comment: See also [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: maybe the AccessController is the only solution for this and the problem is that i am using it in a wrong way. can you please tell me what is the correct way to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Using `AccessController`fixed the issue:

```
    public Boolean SaveToFile(String text)
    {
    final String textEx = text;
    return AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public Boolean run()
            {

    File file = new File("c:\\myFile.txt");

    // if file doesnt exists, then create it 
    if ( ! file.exists( ) )
    {
        file.createNewFile( );
    }

    file.setReadable(true);
    file.setWritable(true);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter( file.getAbsoluteFile( ) );
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( fw );
    bw.write( textEx );
    bw.close( );
    return true;
    } }
 });
```